# Firestore: getting DEADLINE_EXCEEDED on read operations

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Today our application got launched, meaning it started receiving more traffic than usual. But the increase isn't huge. Double of what it was before at most.

But since a few hours, our Sentry logs are full or errors with code `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED`. When I look at the trace, all of them refer to read operations, most of them on single documents (no queries, just singe doc reads), for example: `const res = await fs.collection('coll').doc('doc').get()`;

When I google for this error message, I get a lot of results about issues with writing, especially in batches, but barely anything is written to our database, it's almost exclusively reads.

To give an indication of the amount of reads our database has to handle, we've had 1.2M reads in the past 30 days, with a peak of 60k per day, a number which we haven't exceeded yet today (41k).

What could be the issue in our application?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, I find the answer right after posting the question to StackOverflow. What we saw here was a symptom of our VM running out of memory! After scaling up the server, the problem disappeared.